# Sharepoint 2010 - refresh list job

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, updatelistitems, data-refresh

I need to refresh all my lists in server daily.

To refresh one list I use this powershell:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://Server/ListLocation
$list = $web.Lists["ListA"]

foreach ($item in $list.Items)
{
  $item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
}
```

How to refresh all lists? And how do you create a job so it runs daily at 8:00 p.m.?

Comment: If this is a SharePoint on-prem requirement (which it looks like), then you can create a SharePoint timer job to achieve this. If you don't want a timer job, then the powershell you are using can be scheduled through Windows scheduler in a server machine after making necessary modifications to refresh all required lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PowerShell command to refresh all lists:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb Server/ListLocation
$lists = $web.Lists
foreach ($list in $Lists) {
foreach ($item in $list.Items)
{
  $item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
}
}
```

To run the script daily, I recommend you save the script as ".ps1" file and using Windows Task Scheduler to run the script file daily.

[How to: Run PowerShell Scripts from Task Scheduler](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler)